# Authenticate via session on external domain in confluence

Tags: rest, authentication, iframe, jira, confluence

Is there a way within Confluence where I already have a session, to click an link or go into an iframe on an external domain which might or might not be on the same domain, and make a call to the JIRA api transparently?  I hate for them to login again if they are already in confluence.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to configure trusted communication between JIRA and Confluence: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+Up+Trusted+Communication+between+JIRA+and+Confluence